# Can't run GNU ARM Hello world

Tags: c, arm, gnu

I'm trying to follow this tutorial
http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/test-project/

to run a GNU ARM hello world.

I'm using eclipse luna on windows 8.1 x64.

I've installed the GNU ARM toolchain, and everything else the tutorial states.

The build passes, and gives the result specified in the tutorial

```
> 02:15:01 **** Build of configuration Debug for project ARMTest4 ****
> make all  Building file: ../src/main.c Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0
> -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -std=gnu11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -c -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c" Finished building: ../src/main.c   Building target: ARMTest4.elf
> Invoking: Cross ARM C Linker arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb
> -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g3 -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"ARMTest4.map" --specs=rdimon.specs -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lc -lm -lrdimon -Wl,--end-group -o "ARMTest4.elf"  ./src/main.o    Finished building target: ARMTest4.elf   Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Create Flash Image
> arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "ARMTest4.elf"  "ARMTest4.hex" Finished
> building: ARMTest4.hex   Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size
> arm-none-eabi-size --format=berkeley "ARMTest4.elf"    text      data   
> bss       dec     hex filename    8256       2396     260   10912   
> 2aa0  ARMTest4.elf Finished building: ARMTest4.siz  
> 
> 02:15:06 Build Finished (took 5s.110ms)
```

Then, I try to run, and it fails, I have no idea why. It says "Error starting process"

The details in the error box state

```
> Error starting process. Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\Noam\workspace\cpp\ARMTest3\Debug\ARMTest3.elf": Launching
> failed Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\Noam\workspace\cpp\ARMTest3\Debug\ARMTest3.elf": Launching
> failed Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\Noam\workspace\cpp\ARMTest3\Debug\ARMTest3.elf": Launching
> failed
```

The only thing I can come up with is the code is supposed to run on some emulator and not my PC, which i have no idea how to do.
If this isn't the problem, please tell me what is.

I have also tried many other configurations for the hello world project, to no success.

My expected output for a working result: some console saying "Hello ARM world" to me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't run ARM executables on x64. I guess you're supposed to have an ARM system available, like an emulator or a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @wavemode I think you should write that as an answer.

Comment: The whole point of cross-compiling is to generate code for a _different_ architecture to the one running the compiler, thus you should never expect to run cross-compiled code on the host machine. Why generate ARM code in the first place if you don't have anything to run it on?

Comment: I dont have my chip YET. But still want to start development. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run ARM executables on an x64 processor. The tutorial expects you to have an ARM system available, like an emulator or a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: allright, that sounds good.
How do i get an emulator going?
Thanks

Comment: @Gulzar I haven't the faintest idea.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make comments yet, so this is actually a follow up to wavemode's answer:

The quickest way to set up an emulator is with (depending on your platform) VirtualBox, or QEMU. Install Linux(or another OS that supports ARM binaries) into the image and boot from it. You'll need to transfer the binary to the emulated system, for example by SSH or HTTP.

Finding ARM images is relatively easy, and Debian, Fedora, ArchLinux, and others all provide pre-made images.

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated, the GNU ARM tools are intended to target an external ARM microprocessor or microcontroller and the compiled programs will not run on your workstation.

There are a great number of ARM-based chips and development boards from several manufacturers that can be used with the GNU ARM tools and the idea is usually to create your own system with an embedded microcontroller. The program will need to be adapted for the specific microcontroller and board you are using.

The tutorial isn't clear, but the "Prerequisites" page linked from the tutorial has a section "Assign a device to the project", with a screenshot showing STM32F4-Discovery/STM32F407VG circled - I would assume the author is using that board.

The [STM32 Discovery](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-mcu-discovery-kits.html) boards are low-cost (some under US$20), and include an ST-Link programmer/debugger and interesting peripherals to learn with. Other manufacturers usually have similar development boards featuring their parts.

Comment: The point is that Stack Exchange works best when questions have answers. The question, while old, is a perfectly valid question, and does not have an answer marked, nor are the other answers complete or informative. I'm probably not helping @Gulzar, but I might help someone else. It's still coming up in search results. I was looking with similar words, and saw it multiple times. Old is not dead: I still get frequent upvotes on a question I asked in 2010 (as in literally *today*), and regularly find solutions in questions from that timeframe.

Comment: But this answer do not add anything to the previous answers

Comment: The other answers mention either emulators with an OS or a Raspberry Pi (typically also used with an OS). These come with their own compilers, and are not typically used with a cross-compiler on a separate computer, and are not a suitable targets when learn how to use the GNU ARM toolchain. My answer identifies the type of hardware needed and the specific board used for the tutorial.